# LENOVO CAMPUS THINKPAD X390 - microSD slot not working on Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, sd-card, thinkpad

I recently bought a [LENOVO CAMPUS THINKPAD X390](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x390/20q1?linkTrack=Homepage%3ABody_Search%20Products&searchType=4&keyWordSearch=X390%20Laptop%20(ThinkPad)%20-%20Type%2020Q1) - 20Q1S02M00; it has a tray for a Nano SIM and microSD on the back. I run Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon on this machine.

`system info` outputs [this](https://termbin.com/6e66).

`dmesg` outputs [this](https://termbin.com/mnv1).

`lspci -nnk` outputs [this](https://termbin.com/x4f9).

`lusb` outputs [this](https://termbin.com/05ba).

**Problem**: The microSD card slot is either not working or the microSD card is not recognized. It's neither listed in the file browser as an external device nor is it listed in the Disks application.

**Questions:** 
1. How can I see if Linux Mint actually has detected the microSD slot?
2. If Linux Mint has detected the microSD slot, how can I use it?

Comment: Please post the full output of `dmesg` on a paste site and then post the link here.

Comment: Thank you, i updated my question and provided a link the dmesg output.

Comment: We're probably looking for an [RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (10ec:522a)](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201902-26860), but I could only see the AU9540 USB Smartcard Reader (058f:9540) in the `dmesg` output.
Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/544443/edit) your question and add the output of `lspci -nnk` and `lsusb`.

Comment: Thank you, i updated my question providing the information your requested.

Comment: You cardreader is this device: `01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Genesys Logic, Inc Device [17a0:9750] (rev 01)` (see [here](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/17a0:9750)). There exists a driver with compilation instructions for [Arch Linux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=246658), but I don't think it has arrived in the mainline kernel yet.

Comment: Thanks! This is because the hardware is too new? Do i now have to wait a couple of month until the driver arrived at the mainline kernel in Ubuntu?

Comment: I thought Lenovo Thinkpads have a solid compatibility with Linux :/

Comment: Yes, your hardware it too new and you have to wait. Or try the [Ubuntu instructions](https://gitlab.com/ben.chuang/GL9750-ubuntu/wikis/Readme), just found it.

Comment: Thank you! I will try the Ubuntu instructions and if this does not work, i will wait.